# refresh workspace or upload file to a tomcat server? How to

Tags: file, jsp, tomcat, refresh, workspace

I have a dynamic web project (JSP) on Eclipse that runs on a tomcat server. I create files with GraphViz code, and then I create images with a system call of DOT and I place them in a subdirectory of the project.

All of that works, but now the issue is to show the created images in a JSP page.

As the images are dynamically created they are not in the server neither in the project subdirectory until I manually refresh the project at the workspace.

To solve this problem that I have tried to use the aspectj libraries that contains the IWorkspace, IProject, IFile classes, but it seems that that usefull only if you are developing an Eclipse plugin.

I am thinking about another way to refresh the workspace dinamically or upload the images to the tomcat server.

So the questions are:

- how to upload files (images) to a tomcat server with Java (JSP)?
- how to refresh the workspace dinamically in a non Eclipse (or Eclipse plugin) project?
- how to show images in a JSP page that are not in the project workspace neither in the tomcat server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Tomcat plugin for Eclipse](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/setting-up-eclipse-with-tomcat.html). It probably should help you to solve the root of problems.